# Partially update the current form if the target form has an error, else submit the target form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this idea for the script below:

What the script should do is that when the `form id="try"` is submitted by clicking the submit button, it would not be submitted immediately but rather check if there would be an error on the page where the form is to be submitted.

If there is an error, I can just display an error message by partially updating the div id="content" saying, "Sorry, your user action is currently not possible due to an unexpected issue."

If it has no error (the page "try1.php" was found and has no runtime errors on it), we submit the form and go to "try1.php", not that the contents of the "try1.php" would be sent into the `div id="content"`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
  THIS IS THE DIV: "content"
</div><br>
<form id="try" action= "try1.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Try">
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()   
{
  $("#try").submit(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // get the action
    var action = $(this).attr("action");


    $("#content").load(action, function() 
    {
       //if the action is loaded to the <div id="content"> without any errors:
         document.getElementById("try").submit();

       //else if the target page has an error:
         $("#content").html("Sorry, your user action is currently not possible due to an unexpected issue"); 
    });          
  })
});
```

I'm new to jQuery, do you have any advise on how can I do the if else statement? Is jQuery the right thing to use or are there other solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's a very good attempt, and you're certainly along the right lines using JavaScript / jQuery for client-side validation. Simply chain your `document.getElementById("try").submit();` inside an if/else condition, where you're checking for errors in the form (like `if ($("#content").load(action, function()) { document.getElementById("try").submit(); } else { $("#content").html... }`) :)

Comment: I don't get why the `action` parameter of a form should be checked on every user submit... Is the `action` (destination where to submit the form) dynamic? Then to submit a form to an .html file seems useless, better be a .php, I think.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks! You are right that it is better to use a .php instead of .html as a sample value in the action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the form submit button to a regular button would help, as making this button call a function would do the trick, like:

```
<form id="try" action= "try1.php" method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Try" id="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

Then in the JavaScript part:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // get the action
        var action = $("#try").attr("action");


        $("#content").load(action, function() 
        {
            //if the action is loaded to the <div id="content"> without any errors:
             document.getElementById("try").submit();

            //else if the target page has an error:
            $("#content").html("Sorry, your user action is currently not possible due to an unexpected issue"); 
        });          
    })
});
```

Hope it solves the problem. For more clarifications, please comment.

Comment: What I need in my solution is the if else statement to check whether the "try1.php" have errors or it does not have any error. Then I can now decide whether to partially update the div or submit the form.

Comment: Basically what you did in JavaScript is fine, it just needed a tweak as mentioned in the answer. However, why do you need to be certain?